# xstate: type: final: go back to initial/idle state

Tags: xstate

I have an xstate state machine with 3 states. When data is fetched and final state isreached, the state machine is 'Done'. I would like to go back to initial state of idle after 'finally completing the task'. How do I accomplish that? For example,

```
states: {
idle: {
  id: 'initialState'
},
waitingForA: {
  invoke: { /*Promise*/ },
  onDone: { target: 'wiatingForB' },
  onError: { alert(); }
},
waitingForB: {
      invoke: { /*Promise*/ },
      onDone: {
        target: 'waitingForC',
        actions: assign({ bReturnCode: (context, event) => event.data, })
      }
    },
    waitingForC: {
      invoke: { /*Promise*/ },
      onDone: {
        target: 'success',
        actions: assign({ cReturnCode: (context, event) => event.data, })
      },
      onError{
           target: 'showAlert'
      }
    },
    success: {
      type: 'final' //here, I would like ot go back to idle state;
    },
    final: {target: 'idle'}
  }

}
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention that your code wouldn't be working in the first place. The `onDone` and `onError` events need to be inside the `invoke`. Also, the formatting is a bit messy. Maybe you can do that better in future posts.
In the link below are some tips on how to create a good minimal example that helps others answer your question faster ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `always` transition which transitions to the `idle` state without the need to explicitly fireing an event. Just keep in mind that the success state is not allowed to be a final state otherwise the execution of the service would stop.

You can read more about these automatic ('eventless') transitions in the [XState docs here](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/transitions.html#eventless-always-transitions).

```
  success: {
    // is not allowed to be a final state
    // because you still want to transition to idle
    // and the execution of the service would stop
    always: 'idle',
  },
```

#### Full machine definition

```js
    id: 'some-machine'
    predictableActionArguments: true,
    context: { bReturnCode: null },
    initial: 'idle',
    states: {
      idle: {
        id: 'initialState',
        on: {
          start: 'waitingForB'
        }
      },
      waitingForA: { /* ... */ },
      showAlert: { /* ... */ },
      waitingForB: {
        invoke: {
          "id": "getStuffC",
          "src": (context, event) => debugFetch,
          onDone: {
            target: 'waitingForC',
            actions: assign({ bReturnCode: (context, event) => event.data })
          },
          onError: {
            target: 'showAlert'
          }
        },
      },
      waitingForC: {
        invoke: {
          "id": "getStuffC",
          "src": (context, event) => debugFetch,
          onDone: {
            target: 'success',
            actions: assign({ cReturnCode: (context, event) => event.data })
          },
          onError: {
            target: 'showAlert'
          }
        },
      },
      success: {
        // is not allowed to be a final state
        // because you still want to transition to idle
        // and the execution of the service would stop
        always: 'idle',
      },
    }

function debugFetch() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const delayInMs = 1000
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() <= 0.01) {
        reject('some error')
      }
      resolve('success')
    }, delayInMs)
  })
}
```